# Javascript: How to compare against substring in PDF forms?

Tags: javascript, forms, pdf

I am trying to use some Javascript in a PDF form. As an example, let's say I have two fields: let's call them `TextField1` and `TextField2`.

These fields can be used independently, but when TextField1 has a certain value, I'd like TextField2 prefilled.

This works fine (triggered `onBlur`, not that it matters):

```
var f = this.getField("TextField1");
var g = this.getField("TextField2");

if (f.value == "123") {g.value = "foobar";}
```

My problem is this: How can I compare against a substring of f? I'd like the action to trigger when the first char of f equals "1", but

```
if (f.value.substr(0,1) == "1") { … }
```

or similar have not worked.

Comment: `...have not worked` - why not? What was the expected output vs actual output? Was there an error?

Comment: Well, I would have expected it to trigger the condition and perform the loop, i.e. change g.value accordingly. No visible output, no error, it just fails silently in my PDF viewer.

Comment: You don't include the loop here; we have no idea where that falls in the code. Is the condition triggered? What is `f.value.substr(0,1)`? BTW, I believe `substr()` is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make a string instance from `value`.

You can use one of the following methods:

```
var fStr = f.value + '';
var fStr = String(f.value);
```

and then try to test fStr in a manner you mentioned above: `fStr.substr(0,1) === 'a'`